# Computing $\int_A(\beta z-\gamma y)dx+(\gamma x-\alpha z)dy+(\alpha y-\beta x)dz$

Tags: calculus, integration

We have a circle, $A$, of radius $r$ in the plane $(\alpha z+\beta y+\gamma z=c)$. Using the normal vector $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ to orient the plane and giving C the positive direction w.r.t. this orientation compute the line integral:
$$\int_A(\beta z-\gamma y)dx+(\gamma x-\alpha z)dy+(\alpha y-\beta x)dz$$

Clearly this calls for Stokes' theorem, but I'm not sure what to pick as the vector field. If we have a vector field $(\beta z-\gamma y, \gamma x-\alpha z, \alpha y-\beta x)$ then calculating the curl of the field looks quite messy. Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As you said - this calls for Stokes theorem.

$$
\int_A(\beta z-\gamma y)dx+(\gamma x-\alpha z)dy+(\alpha y-\beta x)dz=2\int\int_D \alpha \space dydz + \beta \space dzdx + \gamma \space dxdy
$$

We know that the normal vector is $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ so from that
$$
= 2\int\int_D \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \space dS
$$

Where $\vec{n}$ is a unit normal vector on our surface (in this case our plane)
And $\vec{F}$ is $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ from the integral

With that

$$
= 2\int\int_D(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \cdot \frac{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}} dS = 2r^2\pi \sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2}
$$

where $r^2\pi = \int\int_D dS$ The surface of area that C encloses.

Comment: In the formula for Stokes', shouldn't it be curlF rather than just F?

Comment: Don't memorize things without understanding them. 
If you look closely you will notice that $\nabla \times (\beta z-\gamma y,\gamma x-\alpha z,\alpha y-\beta x)=2(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=2\vec{F}$ Thats the way i defined F. And calculating it isn't hard in this case.